# How to call a function when using ajax promise

Tags: jquery

I am using the following ajax promise for my application to load states and then districts related to that .

My question is can i call the getDistricts() function after completing loadStates done call ,rather than duplicating the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var loadStates = $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url + '/depo/depo/getstates',
            success: function(response) {
            },
            error: function(x, t, m) {
            }
        }); // End of loading states
        loadStates.done(function() {
            $("#districtsList").html("");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: url + '/depo/depo/getdistricts?stateID=' + stateIDselected,
                jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
                success: function(response) {
                },
                error: function(x, t, m) {

                }
            }).done(function() {
                $("#talukasList").html("");
                var talukhtml = '<option value="">All Mandals</option>';
                $("#talukasList").html(talukhtml);
                  $(".gobtn").trigger("click");
            });
        })
        $("#hideorshow").hide();

}); // ready call ends here


function getDistricts() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url + '/depo/depo/getdistricts?stateID=' + stateIDselected,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(response) {
        },
        error: function(x, t, m) {

        }
    });
}
```

please let me know how to achieve this ??

Comment: Note: You can remove the error and success callback function from the Ajax calls when using promises

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get any Ajax functions to return their own promise:

```
function getDistricts() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url + '/depo/depo/getdistricts?stateID=' + stateIDselected,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    });
}
```

Make all your Ajax calls into similar functions (same is good):

```
function loadStates(){
    return $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
        url: url + '/depo/depo/getstates'
    });
}
```

Then you can just chain the operations.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    loadStates().done(function() {
        $("#districtsList").html("");
        getDistricts().done(function(){
            $("#talukasList").html("");
            var talukhtml = '<option value="">All Mandals</option>';
            $("#talukasList").html(talukhtml);
              $(".gobtn").trigger("click");
        });
    })
    $("#hideorshow").hide();
```

});

### Notes:

- You can remove the error and success callback function from the Ajax calls when using promises
- You are missing code to do anything with the returned values from the Ajax calls, possibly removed for the example, but remember any data values are simply passed to the `done()` callbacks so just add the parameters there.